# How to stop Tkinter LabelFrame from growing when certain text is placed in it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program in which I output an answer into an answer box that I set up with LabelFrame.  It works fine if the ouput is in lowercase.  Capital letters cause the label to expand.  I do not want it to do this.  I want the label to remain the same size. Any ideas?

```
    self.answer_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Answer', height=100) # answer box
    self.answer_frame.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=4, sticky='nesw')
```

The below is not helping if capital letters are the answer:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # locks window from being resized
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: maybe the `grid_propagate` method. http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-methods.html

Comment: So, you're saying you would rather have the text chopped off rather than have the widget grow to accommodate the taller text?

Comment: It actually wont be chopped off.  That's what is weird.  It expands it but there is plenty of room already.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  I use the wraplength and it works.  I didn't have luck with grid_propagate.

```
    self.answer_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Answer', height=100) # answer box
    self.answer_frame.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=4, sticky='nesw')

    self.answer_label = ttk.Label(self.answer_frame, text='test', wraplength=100)
    self.answer_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
```